# How to return reference to temporary value?

Tags: rust

Hi I was wondering how can I achieve the following code:

```rust
struct TimedCache<T> {
    data: RwLock<T>,
    f: fn() -> T,
}

impl<T> TimedCache<T> {
    fn get(&self) -> &T {
        &self.data.read().unwrap()
    }
}
```

Because I obtain: `cannot return reference to temporary value`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite reliably and simply, actually - we don't return `&T`, and instead, we return a trait that the guard implements that allows us to get to `&T`: `Deref`!

```
impl<T> TimedCache<T> {
    fn get(&self) -> impl Deref<Target = T> + '_ {
        let lock = self.data.read();
        lock.unwrap()
    }
}
```

This has all the advantages of having a reference, and none of the drawbacks - you don't even need to know that you're actually manipulating a `RwLock` read guard. To the outside, this looks like an object implementing `deref()`.

A full sample of this, including example of use, is on the [**playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b59db58bd7d0ff6d912ae84645037db5)